# Load and run external .js source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a external .js source that works fine when I use the script internally but I want to make it reloadable using a button, so that when I click the button it loads the script into a div, without having to refresh the page, although I have less... no experience with jQuery and when I use the script...

```
    <button id="SpotifyPlaying">(Re)Load</button>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#SpotifyPlaying").on("click", function () {
            $("#playing").load("/spotifyhtml.js")
         });
    });

</script>
```

It does not appear in the div. the script uses

```
var element = document.getElementById("playing");
element.innerHTML = r;
```

and the code is proper functioning, as well as the div it functions in is here:

```
<font face="verdana" size="3" color="white"><div id="playing" style="height:25px;"></div><br></font>
```

If you need more info, comment please.

The spotifyhtml.js = the contents at [this link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/DeviousRunner/1d31bf3bf6519cf3d38b/raw/3ff7a497f86e4157d8d7eef4b1a95d05d5465fd7/spotifyhtml.js)

Comment: So what exactly should spotifyhtml.js do?

Comment: Where is the "playing" id?

Comment: The "playing" id is in div.

Comment: In order to load and run the external JavaScript file you need to use `$.getScript()` - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: I changed it to $.getScript("/spotifyhtml.js"); and It still dosen't work